# which one is better? O(n^1/2) or O(logn)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Can anyone explain to me which one is better: O(n^1/2) or O(logn). The complexity table in text book says O(logn) is better than O(n) and O(n^2). I think I can conclude that O(logn) is better than O(n^k) where k>=1, but how about when k is between 0 and 1. Is O(logN) still better? Thank you

Comment: where did you get `k` from?

Comment: Why not draw yourself a nice graph of `log n` and of `n^1/2` for `n in [0,25]` or so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While n goes to infinity logn is strictly smaller than n^k where 0 < k < 1. (It can be proved by L'Hopitals rule from calculus I guess.) Thus O(logn) is preferable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is this can be also applied when k is extremely close to 0? Because I think in that case, n^k would be extremely close to 1

Comment: @Sadis seriously, where did you get `k` from.  Not aware of how it would get used in big O notation

Comment: @Tibrogargan it's just another constant. What he asks if this holds for all constants k  where 0 < k < 1 and K is a Real number.

Comment: @Onur It's obvious that it's a constant.  What is not obvious is how it applies to big-o notation.  I'm wondering where the term is coming from, especially since it's going to have a huge effect on the outcome

Comment: @sadfs here's the proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219505/how-to-show-log-n-o-sqrtn  No matter what k is it won't change. You can see from the accepted answer limit always go to zero.

Comment: @Tibrogargan  hi. I'm new about time complexity. that's just thing I made up to express my idea. The original question is just to compare O(n^1/2) and O(logn).

Comment: @sadis Ok, but be careful.  `k` is used in Computational Complexity Theory when calculating limits, but would not normally be used when describing the complexity of an algorithm.  Off the top of my head, O(n^1/2) is not commonly used (.... or perhaps ever), and O(n^k) is just wierd